# How to dynamically set css after effects in angular (6+)?

Tags: css, angular

I want to use variables in angular to dynamically set values in a classes after effects. However I know that [ngStyle] cannot be used to directly set the affect effect values.

In the below example I want to be able to set the colours and percentage of the two colours of the border. For instance the ratio may change over time.

While you can dynamically add classes I dont really want to have 100 classes for each colour (i.e for each %)

```
   
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background:  linear-gradient(to right, #191489 0%,#191489 94.7%, rgba(25,20,137,0.2) 94.7%,rgba(25,20,137,0.2) 100%);
  }
```

i.e.
`background:  linear-gradient(to right, colorVar1 percentVar1, colorVar1 percentVar1, colorVar2 percentVar2, colorVar2 percentVar2);`

How might this be achieved

Answer (score 1):

You can set linear-gradient parameters dynamically by using [ngStyle] and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax. Link to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4vresv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)  with usage example